# Project containing makefile in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have an existing codebase containing a makefile and would like to work on it under Visual Studio 2013. Is it possible? If yes how do I do it? I tried following [these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265200%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) but there is no "Add to project" under "Project". I also tried creating a project from existing source code and the make file didn't get added.

[image: Visual Studio 2013]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to recreate new project inside Visual Studio. Create empty project and after that add all your sources. Going this way you will be "on the Microsoft path" - i.e. you will have relatively small chance of hitting bugs, problems, etc.

Most likely using external makefile is possible but be ready to spend time in investigating differences in implementation, finding cause of mysterious effects, etc.